# Natural action of absolute galois group implies sub extension is galois?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field, $K⊆M⊆\overline{K}$ be intermediate field.

Suppose $Gal( \overline{K}/K)$ acts naturally on $M$, then, can we say $M/K$ is normal extension ?

I have never heard this kind of statement, but I can't find counterexamples.Maybe related with something like infinite version of actin's theorem? But I don't have confident.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the action is the natural one and $M/K$ is separable then yes, otherwise no (try $K=\Bbb{Q},M=\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ and the trivial action, and $K=\Bbb{F}_p(t),M=\Bbb{F}_p(t^{1/p})$ with the natural action)

Comment: Could you give me the reason why the extension is normal ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the point of such a statement is not that the action is ($K$)-*linear*; that it is anyway. (Assuming we are always talking about the natural action of $Gal(\bar K \vert K)$ on $\bar K$.)

The point of the statement is that $Gal(\bar K \vert K)$ *acts on $M$*, i.e. that the action *restricts to $M$*, i.e. that $M$ is stable under that action, i.e. that $g(m) \in M$ for all $g \in Gal(\bar K \vert K), m \in M$. If *that* is the case (and the extension is separable, which seems to be tacitly assumed by saying $\bar K \vert K$ is Galois), then $M \vert K$ is Galois.

Comment: In such a situation, could you tell me why we can say $M/K$ is Galois ?

Comment: What definition(s) do you know for a field extension to be Galois? Or in particular, because as said we seem to assume separability here, for a field extension to be normal?

Comment: I think I  need to prove $＃Aut(M/K)＝[M:K]$ because to check minimal polynomial of root is difficult.

Comment: Don't you know some definition that talks about embeddings into an algebraic closure?

Comment: I didn't know that definition. Could you tell me the definition and how in this situation can we check the definition ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension

Comment: oh I see. You used only (absolute galois group of K)× $F_n$→$F_n$ is defined as map, and not used other axioms of action, correct ?